# Combining dev-machine to container and container to container communication

Tags: docker

How could I solve the following issue:

- Docker-compose project runs two containers with exposed ports

[image]

The containers can communicate with each other using dockers internal dns name, that I can pass as an environment variable, this is ok. `Microservice` reaches `File-Server` by dockers DNS name `compose-project_file_server:80`

From a dev machine I can reach both via `localhost:5555` for File-Server and `localhost:9999` for Microservice.

Now I am testing a piece of software that actually does a curl to the file server and if this is ok, delegates the job to the microservice. Except it does not work that way.

This one obviously works:
[image]

But after I got a 200 from a plain curl, the software automatically does the next step, which fails:
[image]

This cannot work, because Microservice cannot reach `File-Server` via `localhost:5555`, only via `compose-project_file_server:80`

My dev machine on the other hand cannot reach `compose-project_file_server:80`.

What are my options here? I cannot meddle with my dev machine hosts file because the ports are still wrong, and it also feels wrong.

In production this entire scenario is unlikely, the File-Server exists only in an integration-test scenario setup, but it is necessary for various verification steps.

Is there a way to actually bind `File-Server:80` inside Microservice to `localhost:5555` as well for integration tests?